# Find difference between current date and given date in sql and replacing it with given data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, substring, date-difference

[image: Here is the input table]

I have a sql table where a future date is given.I need to find the difference between current date & that given date & store it a function. Answer should be in 3 order in avaibility column:

1. Out of Stock within 30 days -- diff between current date & given date
2. Out of Stock within 60 days
3. Out of Stock within 90 days

func:

```
create function fn_datediff( )
returns date
as
begin

declare @sql
set @sql =
  'select SUBSTRING(Availability,   charindex(date,Availability),
  len(Availability)- charindex(date,Availability)  from [ScrappedData_Regina]'


   returns date
end
```

Final output should replace Availability column data with "Out of Stock within 30/60/90 days"

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.. (And these two have different date/time functions, non of them ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: `DATEDIFF(day,cast(right([Availability],10) as date),cast(GETDATE() as date))` this can find the diff of two date.